# Selecting an element of a function returned record type

Tags: postgresql

How can I select an individual element from a record type returned by a function?
I have tried the following but returns an error near '.'

```
select  working_hours_downtime().downtime from node.
```

the function working_hours_downtime returns a record of two fields message and downtime. How can I get downtime only from the record?
Remember I do not need this.

```
select downtime from working_hours_downtime(...)
```

since it does not suitable for my case since the query is part of a complex select query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose the record in parentheses:

```
select (working_hours_downtime()).downtime 
from node;
```

But if `working_hours_downtim()` returns a `setof` or `table` you *should* put it into the `from` clause.